# Keyboard shortcut to convert simplified to traditional Chinese

Tags: python, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, execute-command

I am trying to create a keyboard shortcut that runs a python script to convert selected simplified Chinese characters into traditional Chinese in the clipboard.

Here are the essential code:

## s2t.py

```
from opencc import OpenCC as CC
import os
import pyperclip
import pymsgbox
import time

cc = CC('s2t')
text = os.popen("xsel -o").read()
rslt = cc.convert(text)
pyperclip.copy(rslt)
pymsgbox.alert(rslt)

pyperclip.paste()
```

Though I can get the script to run as expected in a shell terminal with the command below,

`/home/username/anaconda3/bin/python3 /home/username/Code/python/general_tools/s2t.py`

it doesn't seem to work with the shortcut.

[image]

---

## Update:

Most of the code above worked, but I cannot get `pyperclip.paste()` to run.